# How to avoid .IllegalStateException

Tags: android

```
    02-09 12:06:38.745: WARN/dalvikvm(198): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught     exception (group=0x4001b188)
02-09 12:06:38.766: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due   to uncaught exception
  02-09 12:06:39.415: DEBUG/dalvikvm(198): GC freed 1522 objects / 308248 bytes in 400ms
  02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could    not execute method of the activity
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at  android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
  02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
  02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
     02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at com.ey.eyconnect.Connect_EY.btnSaveActive(Connect_EY.java:1734)
    02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2026)
  02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     ... 22 more
    02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
        02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android. view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
           02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
          02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
       02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
      02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
      02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
           02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
        02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
      02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
            02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at              com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
      02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
    02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
  02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
    02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
    02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper .java:123)
          02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     ... 26 more
         02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at com.ey.eyconnect.Connect_EY.btnSaveActive(Connect_EY.java:1734)
  02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2026)
  02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     ... 42 more
  02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
     02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
    02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
       02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
          02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
     02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
      02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
     02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
     02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 02-09 12:06:39.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(198):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:
```

I need to save a number. when i save for 5-6 times this exception is throwing..

```
  its shown is the   ***background.start();
        Looper.loop(); line*** 
  background is the Thread  and my method for saving a number is :


  public void btnSave(View v) { // Save Button Invoked

 db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();
edt = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.edteyconnect);
edt1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.edtpass);
String prevedt = edt.getText().toString();
String eyid = edt.getText().toString();

    Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    boolean res = false;
    boolean stringres = false;
     db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();
    String eyid = edt.getText().toString();
    Looper.prepare();
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    try {

                            CharSequence char0 = "success";
        CharSequence char1 = edt2.getText().toString();

        res = result.contains(char0);
        stringres = result.contains(char1);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean("key1", res);
        bundle.putBoolean("key2", stringres);
        bundle.putInt("flag", 1);

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setData(bundle);
        handler.sendMessage(message);

    } catch (Exception e) {
         ContentValues values = new      ContentValues();
        values.put(EventDataSQLHelper.STATUS, stat);

        db.update(EventDataSQLHelper.TABLE, values, "ID = " + eyid,
            null);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("flag", 0);

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setData(bundle);

    }
    }
});

// start the background thread
background.start();
Looper.loop();

}
```

Comment: Are you testing android ? Did you write some code for this Jen ?

Comment: Why are you are trying to run your own message loop in the background thread?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are accessing UI elements from within your background thread, which is not allowed.

Do you just want to save in the background on button click to keep the app responsive?
Try using an `AsyncTask` which is easier in my opinion